# About the usage of “oblige”

Tags: meaning, example

> Please oblige me by giving me a lift to the museum.

Please explain the meaning of this sentence or give me some other examples!

I've searched but I can't find a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Which dictionary or dictionaries have you checked, and what specific part of the definition is giving you difficulty?

Comment: It's a formal way to ask for a favor: *Please do this for me*. To perform a service or a courteous act for: "*She obliged me by keeping the personal matter quiet.*" Have you ever visited [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)? It's a great site for more fundamental English questions. Please take their [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) to see if this question (and others you might have) would be a good fit there.

Answer (score 1):

In its original form, to be obliged is to be compelled or bound to do something. You are obliged to obey the law. A worker is obliged to work a certain number of hours as a term of employment and their employer is obliged to pay them a certain amount of money.

And you can as such be obliged by someone or something; you are obliged by the law to not damage other people's property.

If you owe someone something, then you are obliged. As such if someone did you a great favour that you felt must be repaid you might say "I am obliged to return this favour". This led to a new sense where even if you didn't literally mean that you considered yourself to have a debt that now needed to be repaid, "I am obliged" became a way to express gratitude.

And by further extension someone doing something for which you are grateful has obliged you. Hence "Please obliged me by …" means "I would be very grateful if you …".

(The *please" part meanwhile comes from a contraction of "if it pleases you", that is "only do this if you want to, don't feel compelled to" which is polite because it makes it clear that you are requesting something rather than demanding it).